# Storing data in two different databases (MySQL and MongoDB)

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

This is my large question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803690/designing-a-website someone in the comments asked me to split that question up in more answerable questions, so here i go.

In short: I'm creating a webapp, people can join and write messages (and react).

I want to store the user information (usernames, passwords, who's friends with wo) in the MySQL-database, because MySQL is a relational database. The messages (and reactions on them), I want to store those in a document-orientend database (MongoDB).

A few months ago, I saw a presentation about a ecommerce site (i really don't know the name anymore, but in the USA it's really big I think), and they store product details in the mongoDB and user information, billings, ... in the MySQL. On the mongoDB site, it states that is well-suited for storing comments, profiles, session data, ... .

For searching, i want to use SOLR with the MySQL-database (not with the mongoDB because I want only to let users search for other users - those are stored in the MySQL-database - not for comments).

Comment: Is it good to combine 2 types of database (MySQL and MongoDB) and to store the account data in the MySQL-db and the messages/comments in the MongoDB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but if your question is should you use two different type of databases, I would suggest "no" unless you really know what you are doing and why you need to different DBMSs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use two databases for two different purposes. Many cool sites do that.

Comment: I need complex transactions => MySQL
I need scalability => MongoDB
I want to store a LOT of unstructured data => MongoDB
I want speed => MongoDB

I is it possible to gain speed and scalability if I combine MySQL with Sphinx/SOLR?

Comment: yes, you can still do that. After all you can decide where you get your data from.

Comment: on the other hand, unless you have very good reasons and benchmarks that prove one solution is better than the other – in your use case – go ahead and use both. Otherwise why not start out with one (MySQL).

Comment: @v3rt1g0: after you understand what's going on under the hood, MongoDB doesn't seem that fast. You can tune MySQL to comparable write speeds.

Comment: allright: so going with MySQL (only MySQL) and using SOLR for full-text search and caching?

Comment: yes. You can add Mongo without much hassle. It really is nice for all kinds of things.